# Delphi, enhance code of non-virtual methods or events

Tags: oop, delphi

Although more of a Delphi language question, will use a specific example to try and get the idea across better:

using Delphi's TWebModule for an HTTP server, we can define endpoints as actions, and assign those actions an OnAction event, to execute code when a request is made to this given endpoint.

many, if not most of those actions require authorization: that is, they all start with the same block of code that checks for valid credentials and decides whether to allow the request to execute or not. So I started looking at how one could "group" a set of similar actions into maybe a subclass of the default action class (TWebActionItem) that adds authorization-specific code. One might also want to execute some generic before/after methods.

pseudo-code would look something like this, where TAuthWebActionItem is a subclass of TWebActionItem adding authorization code, and before/after method calls:

```
function TAuthWebActionItem.OnAction 
begin
  FBeforeAction // execute some initialization code
  if authorized then // auth ok?
    inherited // proceed
  else
    'you are not authorized'
  FAfterAction // execute some finalization code
end
```

we would then create a TAuthWebActionItem, add it to the TWebModule's list of actions, and we're done.

however, the TWebModule and TWebActionItem classes do not offer virtual methods for overriding.  Using "reintroduce" instead of "override" would not solve it either, as the TWebModule's actions list items are still of type TWebActionItem: calling the OnAction of a superclass, even if reintroduced, will not execute the subclass' code.

How would one bypass such limitations / constraints in the classes being used, to achieve what's outlined in the pseudo-code above?

Comment: You should use the [`BeforeDispatch`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/Web.HTTPApp.TWebModule.BeforeDispatch) event of `TWebModule` for preprocessing.

Comment: ah yes that's definitely a way. one point, though: how will one decide what conditional to execute in BeforeDispatch, without a way to 'categorize' actions, and without hardcoding it? example: if path <> 'Login' then CheckForAuth

Comment: You should indeed test `PathInfo` to know if the URL is public or restricted.

Comment: Your original question is a deep question, but giving your example limits responses to solving that specific problem, I think this does not help to 'make the question clearer' instead it narrows the question to that specific problem.

Comment: While the specific example is solved with the comments provided above, it would be nonetheless interesting to analyze how one would approach the theoretical problem outlined. Surely this isn't a too uncommon problem, maybe requiring altering underlying sources when possible